# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Irtaza' command not found: create-stencil

Tags: npm

i am having this problem i dont know the solution . I have been trying to solve this but till not successful . I tried to make path in environment variable  but it been already there , and i have also clean the cache but still not working  , does anyone having any idea ?

Comment: Hi! Can you say what you're doing with npm to get this error message?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to the space in windows users folder, "C:\Users\John Doe". There are two ways to solve this issue.

1. Create new user without space
2. Updating the npm cache configuration
   a. creating new folder
   npm config set cache C:\Devel\nodejs\npm-cache --global

   b. "npm config set cache C:\Users[Your link name without the bracket]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache"
   (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12380)